# What is console.log without Firebug?

Tags: javascript, console

I've seen a lot of answers to this question but they all involve Firebug, I don't use Firebug and none of the answers were specific enough anyway, so can I view console.log in Chrome Developer tools? If so, where? (screenshot)

Comment: Yes. `Ctrl+shift+I` in Chrome. Or, click the `gear icon`, `Tools`, `Developer Tools`.

Comment: Did you even try opening the Chrome developer tools before asking this question?

Comment: Yeah, I use them all the time, I never noticed that there was a console tab before though, and if I had looked before it was empty so I thought it was useless. (that was before I started using javascript)

Comment: Great :) well we got lots of pretty answers here anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, calls to `console.log` show up in the Chrome Developer tools; the bottom half is a Javascript console, and the messages will appear there:

[image: Screenshot demo]

Comment: Thank you for including a screenshot like I asked

Answer (score 1):

`console.log('dkdf')` just outputs a line on whatever developer console you are using.  Could be firebug or webkit developer tools.  I don't think it's supported on IE.

To see it, on  my mac i do command+option+i.  Or go to the wrench in the upper right, then tools, then developer tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, console.log() messages show up in Chrome's Console.

In Chrome, I personally tend to be lazy, and just right click an element -> inspect element. Then you just switch over to the console tab and it's all gravy.

View -> Developer -> Javascript Console is the non-lazy way to do it.

Comment: That's what I do, too. (Right-click, that is.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a console utility in Chrome too.  It is pretty easy to open up Chrome Javascript Console   and try it:

[image]

The Javascript Console is a tab of the Developer Tools (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools).  To go directly to it:

- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on Mac
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on Windows